# Powershell not splitting string returned from function

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to import a CSV which contains fictional places and hours each day of the week those fictional places are open.

The hours are from 5:00-4:00 format. Some have spaces. I created a function to remove the spaces. After that function is run, it appears PowerShell can't run any further operations on the returned string (i.e. -split).

The CSV:

```
Node,SAT,SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI
PizzaPlace,9:00 – 4:30,0,8:00-3:30,7:00 – 10:00,10:00 – 4:00,10:00 – 4:00,10:00 – 4:00
BigPharma,0,5:00 – 4:00,7:00-6:00,7:00-6:00,0,0,7:00-6:00
GreenHouse,12:00-8:00,0,12:00-7:30,12:00-7:30,12:00-7:30,12:00-7:30,12:00-7:30
Portapoty,12:00-8:00,Closed,10:00-6:00,10:00-7:30,10:00-6:00,10:00-7:30,10:00-6:00
```

The PS1 script:

```
function Unk-AMPM ($openStr) {
    $openStr -replace " ";
}

$csvInputs = Import-CSV SampHours.csv;

$srPRBN = "Our hours for";
$srPRAN = "are";

$dsWed = "Wednesday";

foreach ($csvLine in $csvInputs) {

    $retailer = $csvLine.Node;

    [string] $openWed = Unk-AMPM $csvLine.WED;

    Write-Host "Value of openWed before split: "$openWed;

    $openWedA = $openWed -split "-";

    Write-Host "Value of openWedA[0]: "$openWedA[0];
    Write-Host "Value of openWedA[1]: "$openWedA[1];

    if ($openWedA[0] -eq 0 -or $openWedA[0] -eq 'Closed') {
        $ohsWed = "closed";
    } else { $ohsWed = $openWedA[0] + " to " + $openWedA[1]; }

    Write-Host $srPRBN $retailer $srPRAN $ohsWed "on" $dsWed;

}
```

And the results:

```
Value of openWed before split:  10:00–4:00
Value of openWedA[0]:  10:00–4:00
Value of openWedA[1]:  
Our hours for PizzaPlace are 10:00–4:00 to  on Wednesday

Value of openWed before split:  0
Value of openWedA[0]:  0
Value of openWedA[1]:  
Our hours for BigPharma are closed on Wednesday

Value of openWed before split:  12:00-7:30
Value of openWedA[0]:  12:00
Value of openWedA[1]:  7:30
Our hours for GreenHouse are 12:00 to 7:30 on Wednesday

Value of openWed before split:  10:00-6:00
Value of openWedA[0]:  10:00
Value of openWedA[1]:  6:00
Our hours for Portapoty are 10:00 to 6:00 on Wednesday
```

Comment: I don't see any issues? Do you mean the second record with `0`? Thats because the second record has a `0` in the wednsday column...

Comment: He means the first result with `10:00-4:00`. It should have been split so that `$openWedA` contained two elements with each time, but it seems like it didn't work on that one whereas it did on the others.

Comment: Yeahhh, I totaly missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `–` in the entries with spaces are not hyphens (`U+002D`), but *dashes* (`U+2013`)

You'll usually see this if the data has been copied from a text processor with "automagical" formatting (like Word for example).

Use the "Punctuation, dash" unicode category to match and split both kinds:

```
$openStr -split '\p{Pd}'
```

Comment: The function you modified just removes spaces. I think you meant to put that regex in the `-split`. But I would also include `\s` in the `-split` regex and get rid of that function altogether.